# In how many ways can you divide 21 fish between 6 bears such that no bear would get more than 6 fish?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can you divide 21 fish between 6 bears such that no bear would get more than 6 fish?

Note: It is possible that a bear would not get any fish.

A direction or hint would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly counts as a "way"?  Does it just say how many fish each bear gets, or which particular fish they get?

Comment: The fish are identical

Comment: But the bears are not?  This would be how many ways can you make a sum of 6 terms that add to 21.  Search stars and bars.

Comment: Some context would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I really wanted to reply this on the similar post regarding generating functions, but that one is on hold, so I will do it here.

Actually, ArsenBerk's solution can be simplified a bit further. from his notations,

$$
G(x) = \left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^6.
$$

Formally, this is

$$
G(x) = (1-x^7)^6\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^6 = (1-x^7)^6(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^6.
$$

This means that the infinite series $(1-x^7)^6(1+x+\cdots)^6$ is actually a polynomial, and have to coincide with $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^6$.

More concretely, by induction you can see that

$$
(1+x+x^2+\cdots)^n = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \binom{n+m-1}{n-1}x^m.
$$

By multiplying the previous equation with $(1-x^7)^6$, the $x^{21}$ coefficient of $G(x)$ will be

$$
-\binom 63 \binom 55 + \binom 64 \binom {12}5 - \binom 65 \binom {19}5 + \binom 66 \binom {26}5 = 7872.
$$

---

**Edit:** Inspired by the above formula, we can also give a purely combinatoric method using inclusion-exclusion principle. Let $S$ be the number of methods to divide 21 fishes between 6 bears without restrictions. There are $\binom{21+6-1}{6-1} = \binom{26}5$ ways.

Then we need to subtract by $S_i$, the number of methods such that bear number $i$ get 7 fishes or more, for $i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. To calculate this, we first reserve 7 fishes for bear $i$, distribute the remaining 14 fishes, and then give bear $i$ 7 fishes. So there are $\binom{19}5$ ways to do this. So we subtracted $6\times\binom{19}5$ methods.

But after the previous case, we subtracted the number of methods such that at least 2 bears get 7 fishes twice, so we have to put them back. Similarly, let $i\neq j$ and $S_{i,j}$ be the number of methods such that bears number $i$ and $j$ both get at least 7 fish. We can see that $S_{i,j} = \binom{12}5$ and we have to add back $15 \times\binom{12}5$ methods.

Continue this process, we see again using inclusion exclusion principle that the answer is

$$
-\binom 63 \binom 55 + \binom 64 \binom {12}5 - \binom 65 \binom {19}5 + \binom 66 \binom {26}5 = 7872.
$$

Comment: Thank you for completing, I also learned how to proceed after that step.

Answer (score 2):

Generating function is $$G(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^6$$ and we are looking for the coefficient of the term $x^{21}$. Here, normally in order to avoid brute force, we should express generating function as:
$$G(x) = \bigg(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\bigg)^6$$
and write this as a summation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{...}{...}x^k$ then put $k=21$ and find the coefficient using the binomial $\binom{...}{...}$. However, I could not manage to express is and wrote it to Wolfram but the result is https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1-x%5E7)%2F(1-x))%5E6. The answer seems to be $7872$ from here but my knowledge was not enough to find a general formula for the coefficients of $x^k$ inside the summation. Maybe we should have tried to write generating function as $G(x) = (1+x^2+x^3+...)^6 = \big(\frac{1}{1-x}\big)^6$ and after finding a better expression, making the restrictions given. Sorry that I could not manage to solve it completely.

Comment: Nice. We have not studied generating function yet so that was probably not the intention but that's an elegant use. Thank you

Comment: No problem, if you are familiar to generating functions, I think you won't need any further explanation. Just in any case, you can write if you need.

Comment: That would be really nice if you could show me.

Comment: That would be very helpful as I'm still a beginner @ArsenBerk

Comment: I was trying to solve it completely but I couldn't manage it, instead I ended up using a computational tool to get to the answer. Sorry about that :/